# Jump function on a character

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm creating this 2D game and I'm having problems with the Jump function. It works, the character jumps up and down, but I would like to be able to jump and then move the character while its in the air,e.g. so it can jump onto a platform. I'm using SDLK...

```
case SDL_KEYDOWN:   
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym){
            RArrow = (event.button.button = SDLK_RIGHT);
            Jump = (event.button.button = SDLK_SPACE);

            if((RArrow) && (Jump))
            {
            if(g->getPlayer()->worldY = GROUND_LEVEL)
                {
                    g->getPlayer()->jump();
                    g->getPlayer()->move(10);
                }
            }
            break;
```

This is one of the ways I've tried. I've also tried to make a switch function inside the jump case to navigate left or right but I either didn't code it right or just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with SDLK and how this actually is done in real game development. 
However one way I've implemented this is to see if both keys are pressed on each game tick. So if w+d is pressed the character would go up and right at the same time. But it's a hackish solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

With the implementation listed, looks like the character will only move right when they are on the ground level. You need to change your code so that every tick, the game checks if the character is jumping and if so, moves the character in the direction it is facing/jumping. This code may need to live outside of your event handler.

Ideally, your keyboard event handler would just set a flag on the character indicating that they are jumping and which direction, then in your game loop you call an update() method which actually handles the jumping (and stops jumping when the character collides with the world geometry, like a floor or wall).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't say much more. I'm also not great with C++, which I'm assuming this uses. One way you could implement this is:

- Replace "g->getPlayer()->jump()" with "g->getPlayer()->setJumping()".
- Implement "setJumping()" on the Character to set a jumping flag.
- In the game loop, call "g->getPlayer()->updatePos()"
- Implement "updatePos()" on the Character to update the character's position. In this, check the jumping flag, and if it's true update the position based on your jumping algorithm.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with writing the code you are asking me to implement. Could you elaborate a bit more?